# Memory access in pthreads

Tags: c, multithreading, memory, concurrency, pthreads

I am writing a unit test that involves running multiple threads and I ran into a memory access issue that I can't seem to understand.

Here is the original (pseudo) code:

```
void thread_func(void * err) {
    /*foo will return an allocated error_type if error occurs else NULL*/
    err = (void *) foo(...)
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void unit_test() {
    int i = 0;
    err_type *err_array[10];
    pthread_t threads[10];
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         pthread_create(&(threads[i]), NULL, thread_func, (void *) err_array[i]);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
         ASSERT_NULL(err_array[i]);
     }
}
```

What I am confused about is that all the threads will return NULL (checked with a gdb), however err_array[1] and err_array[5] will be NOT NULL. And instead of a valid err_type, they will contain garbage. In the case of err_array[1] will contain a string of the unit_test file path, and err_array[5] will contain a bunch of access out of bounds addresses.

A work-around I've found is to use a global err_array, and pass in the index for each element to the thread. As well as initializing all the elements of the array to NULL.

My question is why does the above 2 methods work, and not the original code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `err` variable is local to `thread_func`. It goes out of scope when `thread_func` returns. You need to pass the thread a pointer to the thing you want it to modify, not the current value of the thing you want it to modify.

So:

```
void thread_func(void ** err) {
    /*foo will return an allocated error_type if error occurs else NULL*/
    *err = (void *) foo(...)
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

And:

```
     pthread_create(&(threads[i]), NULL, thread_func, (void **) &err_array[i]);
```